Does $\sum_{r = 0}^{ij - 1}\binom{r + n - 1}{n - 1}$ have a specific polynomial expression?
My question: Let $R = \Bbbk[x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}]$, $m = (x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}) \in Spec_{m}(R)$, $I = m^{i}$. I want to compute the multiplicity $ e(I, R)$ related to the Hilbert-Samuel polynomial. Essentially, this involves calculating the leading coefficient and degree of $\dim_{\mathbb{k}} R / I^j $.
My attempt: $R / I^{j} = Span_{\Bbbk}\{ x_{1}^{r_{1}}\dots x_{n}^{r_{n}} | 0 \leq r_{1} + \dots + r_{n} \leq ij - 1 \}$, so $\dim_{\mathbb{k}} R / I^j = \sum_{r = 0}^{ij - 1}\binom{r + n - 1}{n - 1}$. But how can the explicit form of this binomial summation be computed? Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Key words: "hockey stick identity". You'll find this in many sources, like Wikipedia, AoPS, or here on MSE.

You can show (using induction) that
$$
\sum_{r=0}^m \binom{r + k}{k} = \binom{m + k + 1}{k + 1}
$$

Base Case ($ m = 0 $): When $ m = 0 $, the summation has only one term:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^0 \binom{r + k}{k} = \binom{0 + k}{k} = \binom{k}{k} = 1.
$$

The right-hand side is:
$$
\binom{m + k + 1}{k + 1} = \binom{0 + k + 1}{k + 1} = \binom{k + 1}{k + 1} = 1,
$$
thus, the base case holds.

Inductive step: Assume the identity holds for $ m $, we want to show that it holds for $ m + 1 $. You can split the summation:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{m+1} \binom{r + k}{k} = \sum_{r=0}^m \binom{r + k}{k} + \binom{(m + 1) + k}{k}.
$$

By the induction hypothesis:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^m \binom{r + k}{k} = \binom{m + k + 1}{k + 1}.
$$
Thus:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{m+1} \binom{r + k}{k} = \binom{m + k + 1}{k + 1} + \binom{m + 1 + k}{k} = \binom{(m + 1) + k + 1}{k + 1}
$$
Using this identity, your summation becomes:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{ij-1} \binom{r + n - 1}{n - 1} = \binom{(ij - 1) + (n - 1) + 1}{(n - 1) + 1}.
$$
Simplifying:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{ij-1} \binom{r + n - 1}{n - 1} = \binom{ij + n - 1}{n}.
$$

Does this equation have any practical interpretation? After all, $\binom{r + n - 1}{n - 1}$ can be viewed as distributing $r$ balls into $n$ distinct boxes.

You can look at the sum $\sum_{r=0}^m \binom{r + n - 1}{n - 1}$ as the number of paths in a grid with $r$ horizontal and $n - 1$ vertical steps, starting from $(0, 0)$. Each path consists of $r + n - 1$ steps, with exactly $r$ horizontal and $n - 1$ vertical steps. The binomial coefficient $\binom{r + n - 1}{n - 1} = \binom{r + n - 1}{r}$ counts the ways to arrange these steps.
Thus, the total number of paths to the point $(r, n)$ is $\binom{r + n - 1}{n}$.
I'm not sure this is exactly what you need, but I've always found this interpretation useful.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
